# Can't get JTable to refresh/repaint a DefaultTableModel in same instance of GUI run

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh, defaulttablemodel

I simply cannot get my `JTable` to refresh a new tablemodel I create using a method.

I have proved by the `tablemodel.getDataVector()` method that my tablemodel is updated correctly.

However, I cannot get my `JTable` to refresh the view to this new thing.

My `JTable` is on a null layout pane, and sits within a `JScrollPane`.

Relevant code about JTable:

```
private JTable patientTable = new JTable(tablemodel);
      private JScrollPane patientscrollPane = new JScrollPane(patientTable);    
patientTable.setModel(tablemodel);
    patientTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(tablemodel);
    patientTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    patientcard.add(patientscrollPane);
```

Relevant code about what I am trying to do to repaint the table:

```
tablemodel = controller.createModel(patientlist);      
      patientTable = new JTable(tablemodel);
      patientscrollPane = new JScrollPane(patientTable);
      patientTable.setModel(tablemodel);
      patientTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);    
    patientTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(patientTable.getPreferredSize());
       patientTable.validate();
       patientscrollPane.validate();
        patientTable.repaint();
       patientcard.setVisible(true);
       registrycard.setVisible(false);
```

Interestingly, when I call `patientTable.getTableModel()`, it doesn't return a `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: This has typically occurred for me in the past when an attempt is made to update the model from outside of the Event Dispatching Thread. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thanks. I have now added what I believe is a runnable example, with a lot of lines of code removed, and just 2 fields for the patient (first name, last name) etc. You could also run this by testing on any sample CSV of anything with a first name and last name.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have now updated to be even simpler, take a look please

Comment: I should also say that when I rerun the GUI, the new patient and new JTable is updated, and that I am running many windows of the GUI (for testing purposes) at the moment.

Comment: `patientscrollPane.setSize(968, 505);` is also called when I initiate the GUI - is this gonna be an issue?

Comment: You shod the have to recreate the JTable (assuming you already have one which exists), just update the model. I'd avoid screwing with the preferredScrollableViewportSize

Answer (score 0):

try calling

```
 tablemodel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

after updating the table model
don't know whether this is the answer that you are looking for. its been long since i have used swing.

Comment: You should never call the fireXxx methods from outside the model. If you're using the appropriate add/remove/update methods, then this is will get done automatically

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks i will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I post this with great jubilation. The whole issue was with me defining the TableModel as a `DefaultTableModel`, instead of the `AbstractTableModel`, overridinga and creating new `removeRow`, `addRow` and `insertList` methods.

```
public void setList(ArrayList<Patient> patientlist) {
        this.patientlist = patientlist;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

public void removeRow(int row)
{
    patientlist.remove(row);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
} 

public void addRow(Patient patient) {
    patientlist.add(patient);
    int row = patientlist.indexOf(patient);
    for(int column = 0; column < patientlist.size(); column++) {
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }
    fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
}
```

I would suggest anyone creating any custom types of tablemodels from arraylists etc always use `AbstractTableModel`.